Bathroom remodel - shower fixtures to existing pipes?
I bought a new shower fixture kit but the existing plumbing is quite different from the valve types I'm seeing.
The existing pipe configuration:

The fixture I bought:

The new fixture has all 4 connections on top of each other, where the existing pipe has the top one that sticks out:

How can I reconfigure my pipes to be compatible with this all-in-line fixture?

I adjusted the question at the bottom to fit the one in the title, and to keep the question on topic. "Is there a brand I could buy" can basically be answered, "Possibly, keep shopping" and shopping questions are off topic on DIY.SE. How to adjust the existing pipes is on topic.

You could consider cutting back the house's copper pipes and bridging to the new fixture through PEX pipe and Sharkbite connections.
One thought on why to not re-use all of the existing copper pipe: the pipe threads are male on both the pipes and the new fixture. At least some female/female adapters would be needed, as well as some unions to allow threading 4 connections at once.
PEX bends rather easily to make alignment easier.
The new fixture has ears to mount it to wood, so it does not have to be held in place by the pipes.
Mount a piece of wood between the studs, at the correct distance back from the wall face for the new fixture. Mount the fixture to the wood. Clean the ends of the old copper pipes per Sharkbite's instructions. Then run bridging PEX pipes and Sharkbites from the fixture to the old copper pipes.
(Crimp connections might be substituted for Sharkbites, if desired.)

the threaded connections on the new control are made for 1/2 copper to fit inside for a soldered connection. Soldered connections can be made on everything.

Thanks for the replies! I ran across a YouTube video that shows a different fixture from what I bought that will allow for an easier and complete PEX redo. The existing pipes in there are pretty corroded so I am going to do a complete replace and re-engineer with PEX.

The short answer is no. However, you may have enough “play” in your hot and cold runs to line up to the new style. You won’t know for sure until you cut the old one out. Alternatively, you could adjust your blocking for the shower stub out as a 1/2” is all you need to line all 4 up. The pipe that drops for your tub spout is a non-issue. The only thing you want to check is to ensure your shower valve is out far enough to meet manufacturer specs (for finished grade surface) if you go this route. Worst case, you cut the hot and cold lines back a bit and add a couple 45s to offset the difference.

Copper pipe has far more "give" than most people think.  There should be no issue with using the new control fixture you have.
Once you cut the pipe, you will see how much movement you do have.  Adaptation will be need of course to connect male and female threaded parts or change to all soldered connections.
Then you needed to adapt for the setback need to meet final surface specs.
There really should be no worry in using the new control, it just won't be a simple swap. If you do not have confidence in you ability to solder, you should call a plumber.
